# Problem with CreatePage API using gatsby and contentful(Not shown up the content )

Tags: reactjs, api, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I am trying to generate pages of each of the category's data from contentful ...
but there have some concerns.

**Success**

- I could have got the data from contentful ..such as (title, image, and so on ) on the home page(localhost:8000)

**Fail**

- when I clicked the read more button, Card on (localhost:8000), and switched into another page (localhost:8000/blog/tech/(content that I created on contentful)) that has not succeeded and 404pages has appeared(the only slag has changed and appeared that I hoped to).

**Error**

```
warn The GraphQL query in the non-page component "C:/Users/taiga/Github/Gatsby-new-development-blog/my-blog/src/templates/blog.js" will not
Exported queries are only executed for Page components. It's possible you're
trying to create pages in your gatsby-node.js and that's failing for some
reason.

If the failing component(s) is a regular component and not intended to be a page
component, you generally want to use a <StaticQuery> (https://gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query)
instead of exporting a page query.
```

**my-repo**

[enter link description here](https://github.com/taiga-programming/blog-gatsby-contentful)

**gatsby.node.js**

```
    const path = require(`path`);
    
    const makeRequest = (graphql, request) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // Query for nodes to use in creating pages.
     resolve(
       graphql(request).then(result => {
         if (result.errors) {
           reject(result.errors)
         }
         return result;
       })
     )
    });
    
    // Implement the Gatsby API "createPages". This is called once the
    // data layer is bootstrapped to let plugins create pages from data.
    exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
     const { createPage } = actions;
    
    // Create pages for each blog.
     const getBlog = makeRequest(graphql, `
       {
         allContentfulBlog (
          sort: { fields: [createdAt], order: DESC }
          )
           edges {
             node {
               id
               slug
             }
           }
         }
       }
       `).then(result => {
       result.data.allContentfulBlog.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
         createPage({
           path: `blog/${node.slug}`,
           component: path.resolve(`src/templates/blog.js`),
           context: {
             id: node.id,
           },
         })
       })
    });

const getTech = makeRequest(graphql,`
{
  allContentfulBlog (
    sort: { fields: [createdAt], order: DESC }
    filter: {
       
      categories: {elemMatch: {category: {eq: "tech"}}}
    },)
  {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
`).then(result => {
  const blogs = result.data.allContentfulBlog.edges
  const blogsPerPage = 9
  const numPages = Math.ceil(blogs.length / blogsPerPage)

  Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? `/category/tech` : `/category/tech/${i + 1}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/tech.js"),
      context: {
        limit: blogsPerPage,
        skip: i * blogsPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1
      },
    })
  })
});

 return Promise.all([
   getBlog,
   getTech
  ])
};
```

Comment: Can you push the `tech.js` template? it's missing in: https://github.com/taiga-programming/blog-gatsby-contentful/blob/master/src/templates/tech.js

Comment: @FerranBuireu I did push tech.js but the problem might be gatsby-node.js..tech.js based on blog.js and when I confirmed commenting out the blog.js  whether there has a problem or not ..and 404.pages appeared ..if blog.js had a problem, that's pages not appeared I guess ...